# Background Music during Testing iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

I have an app in the store made for runners (Race Me) which lets people play music in the background just fine. I just went to test an update of the app on my phone with background music and upon launch, the new app version turns the music off. Is this true of all test apps? Or did I change a setting in the app update?

Comment: If this helps, I noticed when I build with music already playing, the app works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With music playing try building the app if you're having this problem.